# Why does outerHTML bring back <!-​- --> comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outerhtml

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/QpNbu/3/ - that collects the `outerHTML` for all elements that have `class='active'`. What amazes me is that even if I comment out some of the HTML, as in:

```html
<!--      <div>'Some inner text'</div>  -->
```

`outerHTML` still brings it back! This can't still be in the DOM so I'm wondering where `outerHTML` is looking.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: innerHTML will do the same thing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Comments in HTML are <s>surprisingly</s>, in fact, part of the DOM! If you look in this screen shot here:

[image: web inspector]

You'll see the google chrome web inspector renders it as part of the DOM (notice how the bottom bar shows it as a child of `div#box1.active` as well.)

For more concrete documentation, if you look at the possible `Node.nodeType`s for DOM nodes [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType), you'll see that the `COMMENT_NODE` is one of the valid types.

> COMMENT_NODE  8

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1728279322) also defines the *Comment* interface for the DOM:

> This interface inherits from CharacterData and represents the content of a comment, i.e., all the characters between the starting '<!--' and ending '-->'. Note that this is the definition of a comment in XML, and, in practice, HTML, although some HTML tools may implement the full SGML comment structure.

Comment: Surprisingly? It'd hardly be a complete model of the document if it omitted them.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan my bad, fixed

Comment: It was surprising to me, and apparently  to a lot of other people judging from all the upvotes the answer got.

Answer (score 2):

HTML comments are part of the DOM, they just get ignored by the browser for display.

Comment: That's somewhat contradictory – the browser constructs the DOM; if they're in the DOM, they obviously *weren't* ignored by the browser.

Comment: I presume you mean "get ignored by the browser *for display*."